# C++ function call with incomplete argument

Tags: c++, parameters, default-parameters

I got a question about C++ function call.

Suppose I have defined a function like foo(int a, bool b=true);
But when I try to call it. I use   foo(3), 
Will this function call use foo(int a, bool b=true) ?
Or this is not allowed?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will this function call use foo(int a, bool b=true) ?

Yes, it will use the default argument and `foo(3, true)` will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will (but only in C++, not straight C).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_argument

Answer (score 0):

It is allowed because the second parameter you defined has a default value.